# Ubuntu SSD Failing

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

I tried to boot my Ubuntu system yesterday but the entire file system went "readonly". Then I tried to boot from usb drive to fix it using `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sdb2` but still "readonly". But today I successfully booted. But when I run `sudo dmesg` still some error messages will pop up. Is my SSD broken? Or how should I fix it? Please help me :(

This is the output of `sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sdb2`

```
e2fsck 1.45.7 (28-Jan-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdb2: 1614886/35356672 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 116892960/141399296 blocks
```

Output of `sudo dmesg` (too long so I only pasted a few):

```
[ 2519.376257] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2519.376261] ata6: hard resetting link
[ 2519.690591] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2519.691036] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 2519.691056] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2519.691060] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 2519.691062] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 2519.691066] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 8f 42 bb 90 00 00 08 00
[ 2519.691067] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2403515280 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio
[ 2519.691083] ata6: EH complete
[ 2519.968200] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x880d00 action 0x6 frozen
[ 2519.968227] ata6.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[ 2519.968230] ata6: SError: { UnrecovData Proto HostInt 10B8B LinkSeq }
[ 2519.968234] ata6.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[ 2519.968236] ata6.00: cmd 25/00:88:00:a0:c1/00:00:6a:00:00/e0 tag 5 dma 69632 in
                        res 50/00:90:00:a0:81/00:00:6a:00:00/e0 Emask 0x52 (ATA bus error)
[ 2519.968244] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2519.968248] ata6: hard resetting link
[ 2520.282734] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2520.283005] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 2520.283029] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2520.283034] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 2520.283038] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 2520.283042] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 6a c1 a0 00 00 00 88 00
[ 2520.283045] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1791074304 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio
[ 2520.283066] ata6: EH complete
```

Output of `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.11.0-16-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     GLOWAY STK1.5TS3-S7
Serial Number:    201911280042
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000000 00000016d
Firmware Version: 1.00
User Capacity:    1,440,290,267,136 bytes [1.44 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jan 18 08:58:32 2022 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (   33) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0031) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 19
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4849
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       823
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2921
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       25165836
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       4297326601
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0022   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       14336
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       462
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   030   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 10/50)
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
207 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       36
208 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
209 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       55
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       423
211 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       305
231 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0023   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       63899382656
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       289462459
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16916923868
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       19160212489
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       504446480930

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 518 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 518 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4849 hours (202 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 47 2c e8  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x082c4710 = 137119504

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 10 47 2c e8 80      00:09:10.400  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 46 2c e8 80      00:09:10.400  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 45 2c e8 80      00:09:10.400  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 44 2c e8 80      00:09:10.400  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 43 2c e8 80      00:09:10.400  READ DMA

Error 517 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4849 hours (202 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 2f 2c e8  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x082c2f10 = 137113360

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 10 2f 2c e8 80      00:09:09.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 2e 2c e8 80      00:09:09.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 2d 2c e8 80      00:09:09.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 2c 2c e8 80      00:09:09.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 2b 2c e8 80      00:09:09.600  READ DMA

Error 516 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4849 hours (202 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 d5 2b e8  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x082bd510 = 137090320

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 10 d5 2b e8 80      00:09:08.800  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 d4 2b e8 80      00:09:08.800  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 d3 2b e8 80      00:09:08.800  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 d2 2b e8 80      00:09:08.800  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 d1 2b e8 80      00:09:08.800  READ DMA

Error 515 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4849 hours (202 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 c1 2b e8  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x082bc110 = 137085200

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 10 c1 2b e8 80      00:09:08.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 c0 2b e8 80      00:09:08.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 bf 2b e8 80      00:09:08.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 be 2b e8 80      00:09:08.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 bd 2b e8 80      00:09:08.100  READ DMA

Error 514 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4849 hours (202 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 39 2b e8  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x082b3910 = 137050384

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 10 39 2b e8 80      00:09:07.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 20 38 53 2b e8 80      00:09:07.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 30 53 2b e8 80      00:09:07.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 38 2b e8 80      00:09:07.100  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 10 37 2b e8 80      00:09:07.100  READ DMA

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended captive    Completed without error       00%      4849         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4849         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Thank you :)

Comment: …and what is your question?

Comment: Is my SSD broken? Or how should I fix it? :(